# Integral involving Hadamard product with volume element

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus, exterior-algebra, hadamard-product

Consider the following integral:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}}f(X)(H^T(A\odot dX)V)^{\wedge},$$
where $f:\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}\to \mathbb{R},$ $H\in O(n)$, $V\in O(m),$ $A$ is an $n\times m$ matrix with entries 0,1, and $\odot$ denotes the Hadamard product of two matrices. Is the above integral same as/different from the following integral?
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}}f(X)(A\odot (H^TdXV))^{\wedge}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\o{\otimes}
\def\J{{\cal J}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\vecc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
$For typing convenience, define the variables...
$$\eqalign{
a &= \vecc A,\qquad &\;\,x = \vecc X \\
D &= \Diag a,\qquad &M = \LR{V\o H}^T \\
}$$
The matrices in the first integral can be [vectorized](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products)
$$\eqalign{
J_1 &= \int f(X) \;{H^T(A\odot dX)V} \\
\vecc{J_1} &= \int f(x)\, \LR{V^T\o H^T}\vecc{A\odot dX} \\
  &= \int f(x)\;MD\;dx \\
  &= MD\int f(x)\;dx \\
}$$
Similarly, the second integral becomes
$$\eqalign{
J_2 &= \int f(X)\; A\odot\LR{H^TdX\:V} \\
\vecc{J_2} &= \int f(x)\; D\,\vecc{H^TdX\:V} \qquad\quad \\
  &= \int f(x)\;DM\:dx \\
  &= DM\int f(x)\;dx \\
}$$
These integrals will be equal iff $M$ commutes with $D$.

Since $D$ is a diagonal matrix, this means that $M$ must also be diagonal. This implies that both $H{\rm\;and\;}V$ must be diagonal as well.